# Можно ли в Скайп 8.36 добавлять свои инструменты?

Tags: skype

Если нажать в скайпе для Windows плюсик, который расположен в правом нижнем углу беседы, то появляется панель Инструменты и контент (Bing Search, Gfycat, Погода, Опрос и тд.). Хочу добавить туда свой инструмент, который бы состоял из небольшой формы, нескольких опшнов и крутилок, после ввода текста, все это дело формировало бы запрос к генератору речи яндекса, а результат отправляло бы в беседу. Кто-нибудь не подскажет как это сделать и есть ли такая возможноть?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку